# Get File ID in page after upload file by AsyncFileUpload(ajaxToolkit)

Tags: asp.net

I am using AsyncFileUpload (ajaxToolkit) control for uploading image file from registration page. uploaded file content are store into DB. So I need to show my uploaded file in asp:image control by httphander like `<asp:image id="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images.aspx/id=12" />`. So how to do this.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What you need to show in image tag? File content? or some images like word, excel icons?

Comment: I am uploading image file from  AsyncFileUpload (ajaxToolkit) control. after selecting image it will uploaded and show that image in image control.

Comment: Please share the code you tried for updating ImageUrl="Images.aspx/id=12". In code behind or in inline code?

Comment: I want set it from code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed many site and I got answer of this question..
http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/AJAX-File-Upload-in-ASPNET-with-the-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="afuCompanyLogo" runat="server" 
            OnClientUploadError="uploadError" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"
            UploaderStyle="Modern" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" 
            ThrobberID="myThrobber" 
        onuploadedcomplete="afuCompanyLogo_UploadedComplete" />
        <asp:Image ID="imgCompanylogo" CssClass="imgCompanylogo" runat="server" Height="80px" Width="80px" AlternateText="" />

protected void afuCompanyLogo_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            if(afuCompanyLogo.HasFile)
            {
                FileManagementEntity fileManagementEntity = new FileManagementEntity();
                FileManagement fileManagement = fileManagementEntity.Create();

                fileManagement.FileContentType = afuCompanyLogo.ContentType;
                fileManagement.FileContent = afuCompanyLogo.FileBytes;
                fileManagement.Size = afuCompanyLogo.FileBytes.Count();
                fileManagement.OriginalName = afuCompanyLogo.FileName;
                fileManagementEntity.Save(fileManagement);

                ViewState["logoID"] = fileManagement.FileManagementID;
                imgCompanylogo.ImageUrl = "Image.aspx?id=" + fileManagement.FileManagementID.ToString();
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(afuCompanyLogo, afuCompanyLogo.GetType(), "img", "top.document.getElementById('" + imgCompanylogo.ClientID + "').src='Image.aspx?id=" + fileManagement.FileManagementID + "';", true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing the image as a byte[] in DB;

```
var data = new byte[1]; //Replace this with your values from DB
var mimeType = "application\pdf"; //Replace this with your values from DB
response.ContentType = mimeType ;
response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

This code should be placed in page_load in images.aspx after you have retrieved the values from the DB.

Comment: Seems like the problem is different. Pls see the comment from @Naresh Pansuriya.

Answer (score 0):

Your image page handler page_load method will be

**Images.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(sender s, eventagrs e){

var imagecontent= new byte[XXXX]; // Read DB content as bytes for the passed Id

response.ContentType = 'jpeg/gif/anything' ; 
//this should be a valid MIME type saved in database
response.BinaryWrite(imagecontent);

}
```

**Edit:**

```
From your comments you are trying to update the image tag src value 
from codebehind using Asp.Net Ajax. 

If you want to do this, first make sure your page has access to view state 
information  about those image tags. This is not a big deal, you simply 
wrap the image tags container panel/div with update panel. 

So your ajax request will send the information about those viewstate and 
push the partial update for those image container panel also.
```

Comment: I already done with image page handler but I want to set uploaded image content ID(from DB) in ImageUrl="Images.aspx/id=12" tag. but it not works due AsyncFileUpload control

Comment: @NareshPansuriya what was the final answer? What did you  try? Seems like your update was rejected by some users. Was my solution worked or anything different?

Comment: your solution is also help me for tracking last uploaded file ID from control. I want to show uploaded image file in asynchronous ways